# How to do the Parsing of SOAP Response

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap

I am new in android development.I am getting the SOAP response but I do not know that how to do the parsing of values of the SOAP Response.
Actually I am trying to parse the String "Emotion" from the response.
Please find my XML document and response here http://letsmote.com:8087/EmoteSAPI.asmx?op=GetEmotionList
Here is my code

```
public class EmotionList extends Activity {

    public final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org";
    public final String URL = "http://letsmote.com:8087/EmoteSAPI.asmx";
    public final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetEmotionList";

    public final String METHOD_NAME = "GetEmotionList";

    //SharedPreferences sp;
    String[] Emotionlist;
    EditText edt; 

    Button GetEmotion;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_emotion_list);

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);



                 SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                 Element[] header = new Element[1];
                 header[0] = new Element().createElement("http://tempuri.org/","SecurityInfo");
                 Element APIkey = new Element().createElement(null,"n0:APIKey");
                 APIkey.addChild(Node.TEXT,"BcodTestAPI");
                 header[0].addChild(Node.ELEMENT,APIkey);

                 Element user = new Element().createElement(null,"n0:UserID");
                 user.addChild(Node.TEXT,"bcod");
                 header[0].addChild(Node.ELEMENT,user);

                 Element passid = new Element().createElement(null,"n0:Password");
                 passid.addChild(Node.TEXT, "bcod");
                 header[0].addChild(Node.ELEMENT, passid);


                // add header to envelope
                envelope.headerOut = header;

                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                try {
                        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                        //SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                        Log.e("myApp",envelope.getResponse().toString());

                        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
                        Log.e(" ","----------Response----------"+response.toString());
                        System.out.println("===Response===");
                        SoapObject CinemaCode;
                        SoapObject pii = (SoapObject)response.getAttribute("Emotion");
                        Log.e(" ","----------Response1----------"+response.toString());
                        CinemaCode = (SoapObject)pii.getProperty(1);
                        String []categories = new String [CinemaCode.getPropertyCount()];

                        String []Emotions = new String[1000];

                        for (int i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) 
                        {
                        SoapObject list = (SoapObject)CinemaCode.getProperty(i);            
                        Emotions[i] = list.getProperty(2).toString();
                        Log.e("","Emotions Are:  = "+Emotions[i]);

                        }
                }catch(Exception e)
                {

                }

            }
```

Here is the response which I am getting....

09-25 11:38:20.357: E/(626): ----------Response----------anyType{Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Joy; Color=#9370DB; EmotionId=17; IsHappyEmotion=true; }; Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Freedom; Color=#800080; EmotionId=12; IsHappyEmotion=true; }; Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Love; Color=#8B008B; EmotionId=19; IsHappyEmotion=true; }; Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Passion; Color=#008080; EmotionId=21; IsHappyEmotion=true; }; Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Enthusiasm; Color=#B8860B; EmotionId=10; IsHappyEmotion=true; }; Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Optimism; Color=#696969; EmotionId=20; IsHappyEmotion=true; }; Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Hopefulness; Color=#98F5FF; EmotionId=15; IsHappyEmotion=true; }; Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Contentment; Color=#0000FF; EmotionId=4; IsHappyEmotion=true; }; Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Boredom; Color=#8A2BE2; EmotionId=3; IsHappyEmotion=false; }; Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Pessimism; Color=#48D1CC; EmotionId=22; IsHappyEmotion=true; }; Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Frustration; Color=#FFC0CB; EmotionId=24; IsHappyEmotion=false; }; Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Disappointment; Color=#D2691E; EmotionId=7; IsHappyEmotion=false; }; Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Doubt; Color=#CAFF70; EmotionId=9; IsHappyEmotion=false; }; Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Worry; Color=#008000; EmotionId=23; IsHappyEmotion=false; }; Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Blame; Color=#7CFC00; EmotionId=2; IsHappyEmotion=false; }; Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Discouragement; Color=#ADFF2F; EmotionId=8; IsHappyEmotion=false; }; Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Jealousy; Color=#006400; EmotionId=16; IsHappyEmotion=false; }; Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Guilt; Color=#FFFF00; EmotionId=13; IsHappyEmotion=false; }; Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Loneliness; Color=#BDB76B; EmotionId=18; IsHappyEmotion=false; }; Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Fear; Color=#FF8C00; EmotionId=11; IsHappyEmotion=false; }; Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Anger; Color=#FF0000; EmotionId=1; IsHappyEmotion=false; }; Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Depression; Color=#8B0000; EmotionId=5; IsHappyEmotion=false; }; Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Despair; Color=#CD5C5C; EmotionId=6; IsHappyEmotion=false; }; Emotions=anyType{Emotion=Hatred; Color=#800000; EmotionId=14; IsHappyEmotion=false; }; }

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method and check if it works

```
public void Parser(){

        class TopGoalScores {
            String Emotion;
            int Color;
            String EmotionId;
            String IsHappyEmotion;

        }

        TopGoalScores topGoalScores=new TopGoalScores();

         try {
            SoapParser.parseBusinessObject(response.getProperty(0).toString(), topGoalScores);

         } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
         }


    }
```

This is Soap Parser Class

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class SoapParser {

    /**
     * Parses a single business object containing primitive types from the
     * response
     * 
     * @param input
     *            soap message, one element at a time
     * @param theClass
     *            your class object, that contains the same member names and
     *            types for the response soap object
     * @return the values parsed
     * @throws NumberFormatException
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InstantiationException
     */
    public static void parseBusinessObject(String input, Object output)
            throws NumberFormatException, IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {

        Class theClass = output.getClass();
        Field[] fields = theClass.getDeclaredFields();

        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            Type type = fields[i].getType();
            fields[i].setAccessible(true);

            // detect String
            if (fields[i].getType().equals(String.class)) {
                String tag = "s" + fields[i].getName() + "="; // "s" is for
                                                                // String in the
                                                                // above soap
                                                                // response
                                                                // example +
                                                                // field name
                                                                // for example
                                                                // Name =
                                                                // "sName"
                if (input.contains(tag)) {
                    String strValue = input.substring(
                            input.indexOf(tag) + tag.length(),
                            input.indexOf(";", input.indexOf(tag)));
                    if (strValue.length() != 0) {
                        fields[i].set(output, strValue);
                    }
                }
            }

            // detect int or Integer
            if (type.equals(Integer.TYPE) || type.equals(Integer.class)) {
                String tag = "i" + fields[i].getName() + "="; // "i" is for
                                                                // Integer or
                                                                // int in the
                                                                // above soap
                                                                // response
                                                                // example+
                                                                // field name
                                                                // for example
                                                                // Goals =
                                                                // "iGoals"
                if (input.contains(tag)) {
                    String strValue = input.substring(
                            input.indexOf(tag) + tag.length(),
                            input.indexOf(";", input.indexOf(tag)));
                    if (strValue.length() != 0) {
                        fields[i].setInt(output, Integer.valueOf(strValue));
                    }
                }
            }

            // detect float or Float
            if (type.equals(Float.TYPE) || type.equals(Float.class)) {
                String tag = "f" + fields[i].getName() + "=";
                if (input.contains(tag)) {
                    String strValue = input.substring(
                            input.indexOf(tag) + tag.length(),
                            input.indexOf(";", input.indexOf(tag)));
                    if (strValue.length() != 0) {
                        fields[i].setFloat(output, Float.valueOf(strValue));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Also Tutorial with Source code**

see this [link](http://thiranjith.com/2012/10/15/introduction-to-working-with-ksoap2-in-android/)